# Why is python reading code that is in a else statement when it shouldn't

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner python programmer and I run into a problem that I could not resolve to do with list index out of range.

```
originalList = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
outputList = []
for i in range(len(originalList)):
    if i == len(originalList):
        outputList.append([originalList[i],originalList[0]])
    els:
        outputList.append([originalList[i], originalList[i+1]])

print(outputList)
```

I would need the output to be:

```
outputList = [[['a','b'],['c','d']],[['c','d'],['e','f']],[['e','f'],['a','b']]]
```

however when I try to run this code, it gives me an list index out of range at line 7 error.
I do not know why is this error happening sins python shouldn't even run the code at line 7 if **i** in equal to the length of the list.

Comment: Lists start at `0`. You can't read the `i`th element of a list if `i == len(originalList)`. Also please post your _actual_ code (`els:` is not a valid Python keyword).

Comment: Have you printed the values of `i` and `len(originalList)` to see what their values are?

Comment: because `i` holds value from 0 to 2, and since it is compared against `length` of list, which is `3`, the `if` condition is never going to be `True` thus it will execute the else part only

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Your posted code does not run due to a typo.  We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  A simple `print` shows the obvious reason: when `i` is 2, you try to access elements 2 and 3, causing the error.

Comment: See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  This is not a Stack Overflow problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change
`if i == len(originalList):` to `if i == len(originalList)-1:`

Explanation:
A list starts at index 0, therefore your list with N elements will have all the indexes from 0 to N-1, meaning your last element will be at index N-1.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it out by changing line 7 from this:

```
outputList.append([originalList[i], originalList[i+1]])
```

to this:

```
outputList.append([originalList[i], originalList[-1-i]])
```